# Deleting multiple lines from a txtFile

Tags: java, bufferedreader, printwriter, temporary-files

What I'm trying to do is to delete a reservation I made
The reservation look like this in the txt file

```
08:00
Niel Butaye
1
```

The code That I have to delete the reservation is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ReservatieVerwijderen {
    static String naamklant="";
    public ReservatieVerwijderen() {}

  public void removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {

    try {

      File inFile = new File(file);

      if (!inFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
        return;
      }

      //Maak een nieuw bestand dat later het originele bestand wordt
      File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

      String line = null;

      //Lees het originele bestand en schrijf naar het tijdelijke bestand 
      //Als de lijn == de lijn die we zoeken schrijven we dit niet over
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

          pw.println(line);
          pw.flush();
        }
      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Verwijder het originele bestand
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      } 

      //Hernoem het tijdelijke bestand naar het originele
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReservatieVerwijderen util = new ReservatieVerwijderen();
    SimpleInOutDialog  input = new SimpleInOutDialog("Reserveringen");
    naamklant = input.readString("Geef de volledige naam in");
    util.removeLineFromFile("L:\\Documents/Informatica/6de jaar/GIP/Reserveringen.txt", naamklant);
  }
}
```

It only deletes the name of the reservation maker , I need to delete the hour(08:00) and kind of reservation(1) too. Any help ?

```
public class SimpleInOutDialog {

    private String titel;

    /**
     * Constructor van een SimpleInOutDialog.
     *
     * @param titel een String met de titel van het venstertje.
     */
    public SimpleInOutDialog(String titel) {
        this.titel = titel;
    }
    /**
     * Tonen van een tekst in een dialoogvenstertje. 
     * @param message een String met een te tonen berichtje.
     * @param output een String met de te tonen tekst.
     */
    /**
    *  
    * @param 
    */


    public void showString(String message, String output) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null,
            message + "\n\n" + output + "\n\n",
            titel,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }

    /**
    * Tonen van een geheel getal in een dialoogvenstertje.  
    * @param message een String met een te tonen berichtje.
    * @param een int met het te tonen getal.
    */
    public void showInteger(String message, int getal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null,
            message + "\n\n" + Integer.toString(getal) + "\n\n",
            titel,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }

    /**
    * Tonen van een geheel getal in een dialoogvenstertje.
    * @param message een String met een te tonen berichtje.  
    * @param een double met het te tonen getal.
    */
    public void showDouble(String message, double getal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null,
            message + "\n\n" + Double.toString(getal) + "\n\n",
            titel,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Inlezen van een String.
     * @param message een String met de tekst die in het dialoogvenster
     * moet getoond worden.
     * @return de ingelezen String.  Indien het venster zonder
     * invoer wordt afgesloten is de String null.
     */
    public String readString(String message) {
        Object[] possibilities = null;
        String s = null;
        s =
            (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                message,
                this.titel,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                possibilities,
                "");

        if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0)) {
            s = null;
        }
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Inlezen van een geheel getal.
     * @param message een String met de tekst die in het dialoogvenster
     * moet getoond worden.
     * @return het ingelezen geheel getal (een int).  Indien het venster zonder
     * correcte invoer wordt afgesloten is het getal 0 (nul).
     */
    public int readInteger(String message) {
        boolean isAnInteger = false;
        String tekst = null;
        int gelezen = 0;
        while (!isAnInteger) {
            tekst = readString(message);
            if (tekst != null) {
                try {
                    gelezen = Integer.parseInt(tekst);
                    isAnInteger = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    isAnInteger = false;
                }
            } else {
                isAnInteger = true;
                gelezen = 0;
            }
        }
        return gelezen;
    }

    /**
     * Inlezen van een kommagetal.
     * @param message een String met de tekst die in het dialoogvenster
     * moet getoond worden.
     * @return het ingelezen getal (een double).  Indien het venster zonder
     * correcte invoer wordt afgesloten is het getal 0.0 (nul).
     */
    public double readDouble(String message) {
        boolean isADouble = false;
        String tekst = null;
        double gelezen = 0.0;
        while (!isADouble) {
            tekst = readString(message);
            if (tekst != null) {
                try {
                    gelezen = Double.parseDouble(tekst);
                    isADouble = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    isADouble = false;
                }
            } else {
                isADouble = true;
                gelezen = 0.0;
            }
        }
        return gelezen;
    }

    /**
     * Wanneer je in je programma geen uitvoer meer nodig hebt 
     * MOET je deze bewerking op het SimpleInOutDialog-object uitvoeren.
     * Het programma wordt dan beëindigd.
     */
    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get much cleaner code if you think in complete reservations instead of individual lines:

```
void deleteReservations(String reservationName, BufferedReader input,
      PrintWriter output) throws IOException {
    String date;
    while ((date = input.readLine()) != null) {
      String name = input.readLine();
      String tickets = input.readLine();

      // You can check any part of a reservation here
      // to figure out wether to keep or delete it.
      if (!name.equals(reservationName)) {
        output.println(date);
        output.println(name);
        output.println(tickets);
      }
    }
  }
```

This will obviously fail on files that are not following the 3-line-block format, but then again, the file is broken anyway.

Sample input based on Sergey Brenner's answer:

```
08:00
Niel Butaye
1
09:00
dean koontz
2
10:00
stephen king
3
```

given the name `dean koontz` outputs:

```
08:00
Niel Butaye
1
10:00
stephen king
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a fine and safe way to store reservation entities in a text file like you do, I have debugged your code related to manipulating the text file. In your `removeLineFromFile()` method change your while loop to the code below and it will be done.

```
boolean go = true;
while ( go )
{
    String temp = "";
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        line = br.readLine();
        if ( line != null )
            temp += line + "\n";
        else
            go = false;
    }

    if ( !temp.trim().contains( lineToRemove ) )
    {
        pw.print( temp );
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you put    pw.close();
   br.close(); after the while loop?

Comment: Now did it and it works perfect ! Thank you very much! You just made my weekend!

Comment: @deporter +1 for tagging the line with the name `temp += line + "\n";` for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend put a marker like $$ at the start and at the end of your reservation to delete or sort of a tag for it if possible when you create a file for it. If the location of the reservation in the file is the same always you can iterate through file and check the needed lines to remove.

You have taken the code from here http://www.javadb.com/remove-a-line-from-a-text-file which requires a string as a parameter to be deleted. 
So you have to know beforehand which exact line has to be removed.

EDIT:

input file

```
08:00
Niel Butaye
1
09:00
dean koontz
1
10:00
stephen king
1
```

---

```
    public static int  findLineToDelete(String file, String lineToRemove) {
     int lineFound=0;
    try {

      File inFile = new File(file);

      if (!inFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
        return -1;
      }

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      String line = null;

      //Lees het originele bestand en schrijf naar het tijdelijke bestand 
      //Als de lijn == de lijn die we zoeken schrijven we dit niet over
      int i=0;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         i++;
        if (line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {  
            System.out.println(i);
          lineFound=i;          
        }
      }

      br.close();

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  return lineFound;
  }

public static void removeNthLine(String f, int toRemove) throws IOException {

    File tmp = File.createTempFile("tmp", "");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmp));
    int i=0;
    String l=null;
        System.out.println("toRemmove"+toRemove);
    while (null != (l = br.readLine())){
        i++;
        if(i!=toRemove-1&&i!=toRemove&&i!=toRemove+1){
          System.out.println(l);
          bw.write(String.format("%s%n", l)); 
         }
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

    File oldFile = new File(f);
    if (oldFile.delete())
        tmp.renameTo(oldFile);

   }
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    int found = findLineToDelete("a.txt", "dean koontz");
    System.out.println(found);
    try{
    removeNthLine("a.txt",found);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

  }
```

hope it helps abit.

Comment: If I put like $$ at the start and the end, he will not find the file that I'm looking for beacause there are multiple reservations in the file and then they would all be deleted, right? Is there a way to say when he found the string I was looking for, to not copy the line before and after to the tempfile?

Comment: if you have exactly three lines of reservation you iterate through file get the number of the line and delete the one after with index +1 and the one before this line with an index of -1 of the needed line. I assume you have the name of a person who made the reservation in between. Here's a sample of deleting the Nth line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477762/java-delete-line-from-text-file-by-overwriting-while-reading-it

Comment: Yes the name is in between , so I need to change to class a bit so It reads the file and if he finds the line I was looking for he needs to get the number , so I can determine the number before and after. Then he copies everything to the new file except those lines? Do you know to how the get that in my code perhaps?

Comment: If you have noticed my previous comment there's a code there which removes the desired line under certain number. Okay I'll see to it in  a sec.

Comment: Yes , read that post too , but it deletes the line with the inputnumber , don't really figure out how to delete the line before and after.. Thank you very much!

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but it should be something like that. Tell me your input when you've tested it.

Comment: Tested it and it doesn't work. My input was the name Niel Butaye , and he didn't delete anything..

Comment: @NB I have just tested my code and it works the same. I'm updating the code.

Answer (score -1):

The Below Example can easily delete multiple lines from the text File.

Enter file name.

Enter First line no:

Enter no. of lines, you want to delete.

Check below example under comment!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.FileWriter;


public class RemoveLines



{   
public static void main(String[] args)
{

   //Enter name of the file here
    String filename="foobar.txt";

    //Enter starting line here

    int startline=1;

    //Enter number of lines here.
    int numlines=2;

    RemoveLines now=new RemoveLines();
    now.delete(filename,startline,numlines);
}
void delete(String filename, int startline, int numlines)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        //String buffer to store contents of the file
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");

        //Keep track of the line number
        int linenumber=1;
        String line;

        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            //Store each valid line in the string buffer
            if(linenumber<startline||linenumber>=startline+numlines)
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            linenumber++;
        }
        if(startline+numlines>linenumber)
            System.out.println("End of file reached.");
        br.close();

        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(new File(filename));
        //Write entire string buffer into the file
        fw.write(sb.toString());
        fw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went horribly wrong: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanations. What did you change? What was OPs mistake in the first place?