# How to delete a line from text file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am creating one application in Java swing api. I am using txt file as my database to store,update etc. I completed storing procedure successfully. But I cant update .If I click update button on my application the data in file could not be replaced. can you please tel me how to replace a data in file?

Thanks in advance...

```
import java.io.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String data = null;
            File file = new File("student.txt", true);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] de = data.split(" ");
                if (de[0].equals("vimal")) {
                    data.trim();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: have you red the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? also, if posting code, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You'll probably realize that by only telling _I can't update_, or _data in the file could not be replaced_, it's exceedingly unlikely that someone can reasonably answer this question. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: As `java.io.File` has no such constructor; this example fails to compile.

Comment: What's the swing tag for? I can't see a single Swing-UI element in your code.

Comment: See this response , might help you [Java - delete line from text file by overwriting while reading it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6477893/945317

Answer (score 0):

you need to close your buffered reader after all 
and in your fileReader need an "True"

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      String data= null;
      File file=new File("student.txt");
      FileReader fr =new FileReader(file,true);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      while((data=br.readLine())!= null) {
        String[] de = data.split(" "); 
        if(de[0].equals("vimal")) {
           data.trim();
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    br.close()
  }
 }
```

Comment: Pleas format your code; `java.io.File` has no such constructor.

Comment: `String` literals must be quoted, and the example remains almost unreadable.

Comment: If you do the effort of posting an answer to indicate the reader must be closed, at least put it in a `finally` block