# Java, Is it possible to replace Nth line of a file with a string without creating a temp file?

Tags: java

The only way I have managed is to create a temp file to do this, but this is not what I want. Can someone provide an example of how to replace the Nth line of a text file with a string WITHOUT making a temp file.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: a temp file is the right wa.  Why not?

Comment: Look into RandomAccessFiles (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html). This should let you do what you want.

Comment: Is the length of the string, in bytes, equal to the length of the existing line, in bytes?

Comment: trust me it wont work for what i'm using this for

Comment: How is this file being used? Is it a property file?

Comment: @JessicaMcDaniel please use `@<userName>` in your comments to answer to somebody

Answer (score 1):

You can use RandomAccessFile...this provides read and write to file at same time...so you dont need to create temp file...

Idea is to skip through N-1 th line using readLine..

then count bytes of seventh line and compare with your replaceString bytes...

if replaceStringBytes < seventhLineBytes then replace entire seventh line bytes and continue reading after seventh line and moving the bytes before in file...

if replaceStringBytes > seventhLineBytes then create buffer of difference in bytes and store additional bytes after seventh line... continue filling up the buffer with difference each time you move forward...

here is a thread which will give you some hint...

[Java - delete line from text file by overwriting while reading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477762/java-delete-line-from-text-file-by-overwriting-while-reading-it)